# Why do collections in java not have a read only iterator concept?

Tags: java, design-patterns, collections

The [Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)  interface of java has 2 methods

1. hasNext()
2. next()

Why doesn't [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) extend Enumeration and add the remove method()?

Also, if all I want to do is loop over my collection, I can make do with an Enumeration (or an iterator if it extends enumeration) as loop statements only need an enumeration. I don't have to worry about the collection getting modified

Comment: I think you meant, why doesn't `Enumeration` extend from `Iterator` - as `Iterator` already has the `remove()` method.

Comment: `Enumeration` does not have the two methods you describe. Instead, it has `hasMoreElements()` and `nextElement()`. See the API docs.

Answer (score 7):

> Why doesn't `Iterator` extend `Enumeration` and add the `remove()` method?

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

> `Iterator` takes the place of `Enumeration` in the Java Collections Framework. Iterators differ from enumerations in two ways:
>
> - Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics.
> - **Method names have been improved.**

I suspect the latter is the real reason for introducing a brand new interface instead of extending the existing one.

> Also, if all I want to do is loop over my collection, I can make do with an Enumeration (or an iterator if it extends enumeration) as loop statements only need an enumeration. I don't have to worry about the collection getting modified

Well, if you don't want to modify the collection, then don't call `remove()`. If you really, really don't trust yourself, you could use [`Collections.unmodifiableCollection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29) et al to create a read-only wrapper.

Finally, it is worth noting that if you use a for-each loop to iterate over the collection, you don't have access to the `remove()` method anyway:

```
for (String s : str_list) {
   ...
}
```

Here, we are using the `Iterator` interface, but don't have access to the actual iterator object.

Comment: Regarding the "then don't call `remove()`" comment: for API designers this can be a real issue. It is by no means just a "do I trust myself" question/issue. The runtime approach via unmodifiable collections prevents the worst. But it is far from ideal.

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableCollection() is exactly what is needed. If you build an api, you cannot trust any user of the api. And creating a copy of the internal structure is not an option in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

You could just obtain a java.util.Enumerator from your collection, via the [java.util.Collections.enumeration()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#enumeration%28java.util.Collection%29) Method.

Anyway, if you don't want to modify your collection via its iterator, it's just a matter of not calling the remove() method.

Comment: The idea is to forbid it, because you may not want to, but you never know who is going to be touching your code soon enough.

Answer (score -1):

According to http://www.journaldev.com/1330/java-collections-interview-questions-and-answers#iterator-vs-enumeration, "Enumeration is twice as fast as Iterator and uses very less memory. Enumeration is very basic and fits to basic needs."

So, I guess if you don't need remove(), then using Enumeration is more effective than using Iterator.

Comment: "Enumeration is twice as fast as Iterator and uses very less memory." - That's not just bad English, it's also wrong. The performance of ```Enumeration``` vs. ```Iterator``` depends on the implementation. Each collection can have its own implementation of these interfaces, so any general statement about their performance is nonsense.